# Excel whitespace contains hidden 0

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have workseets with cells containg trailing whitespaces. I have tried using various VBA methods to strip these whitespaces out. However none have been successful. After examining if I copy the white space `"207.6100   "` and paste it in notepad,  there is a 0 in it `"0 "` can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: To help future visitors, please see my comment on Gary's answer? (Maybe SimonSays' answer is actually the explanation people will be looking for.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the cells you wish to "clean-up" and run this small macro:

```
Sub KleanCell()
  Dim r As Range, CH As String, v As String
  Dim v2 As String

  For Each r In Selection
    v = r.Text
    CH = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(v)
      v2 = Mid(v, i, 1)
      If IsNumeric(v2) Or v2 = "." Then
        CH = CH & v2
      End If
    Next i
    r.Clear
    r.Value = CDbl(CH)
  Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

To see what is actually in a cell, click on it and run this macro:

```
Sub WhatIsInThere()
   Dim L As Long, v As String
   Dim i As Long, msg As String
   v = ActiveCell.Text
   L = Len(v)
   msg = L & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

   For i = 1 To L
      msg = msg & i & vbTab & Mid(v, i, 1) & vbTab & Asc(Mid(v, i, 1)) & vbCrLf
   Next i
   MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

Comment: I have have found that I can clean the cells with `String = Replace(String, vbTab, " ")`  I am still confused why there appears to be a hidden 0 in the whitespace

Comment: It may display as a zero, but may not be a "real" zero.

Comment: @TomRuh  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thank you @Gary's Student,  That is really interesting. Can you recomend where I can learn to decypher it?

Comment: @TomRuh  What the second macro does is to grab a cell and then character-by-character outputs the characters and the ASCII code associated with the character.

Comment: @Tom, since you accepted this answer, apparently your question about what the `0` is, is solved? Care to tell us what the WhatIsInThere showed you? Was the ASCII code of what seemed to be copied as a `0` indeed the expected value `48`? Or something else? (Your `Replace(String, vbTab, " ")` seems to suggest it should have been `9` for a tab character instead, and maybe SimonSays is right and there was nothing *after* the tab, making Excel show a zero to indicate "no value", aka NULL?)

Comment: I'm betting the trailing character is a `Tab` based on the OPs above comment *I have have found that I can clean the cells with String = Replace(String, **vbTab**, " ")*. This data may have been imported from another source that was tab-delimited.

Comment: @Twisty  I offered up the second macro to help display this kind of junk.  Depending on the font, junk can appear to be a zero or a question mark or even a small black square.  I always look for the ASCII code.

Comment: Yes, and that's the best way to answer this question. I was simply speculating in response to @Arjan's query.

Answer (score 0):

The "0" you are seeing in your cell values padded after the actual number is an artifact of MS Excel called the "[NULL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null)". This is a filler "Black Hole" which is used in many database systems; even Oracle Database uses it. The "NULL" manifests itself into an "0".

Comment: I feel you're right, but: any reference for this? As Tom commented that `Replace(String, vbTab, " ")` helped getting rid of the zero, I guess the contents were something like a number and a trailing tab, making Excel interpret this as *two* values (value 1, tab, value 2) for which the second value was missing (aka NULL), which then showed as a zero on copying?

Answer (score -2):

Use the `Trim()` function.
If even that doesn't work use `Val(Trim())`.

Comment: Yes Trim() would work, unless there is a hidden character in the whitespace. However my question was not how to use Trim() it was to understand the character.

Comment: In this case could you give us an example, uploaded file or whatever. You expect a solution to a malfunction we cannot reproduce. There are thousands of standard characters and we'd need to parse them in situ to find something useful.

Comment: Just so you know I have copied your exact string and `ActiveCell.Value2 = Len(Trim(ActiveCell.Value2))` gave the result of *8* just like it should've.

Comment: You have not answered the question of why there is a hidden "0". Please read *[How do I write a good answer?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer).